# How to display markers on google maps from sqlite database on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Firstly sorry for my bad english. I want to make a program that displays markers on google maps api v2 (android) taking coordinates from SQLite database. Do you know any examples, I am a novice in this topic. The database will be created manually, then I would connect it to the program.

Comment: i suggest you to follow this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598400/add-markers-to-map-from-sqlite-and-center-fit-them-in-zoom-android